# @Sql not work @BeforeTransaction Spring Testing Annotations

Tags: java, sql, spring, junit, spring-test

[`@BeforeTransaction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/transaction/BeforeTransaction.html) (beforeTransaction method) have to run SQL commands in start.sql after that [`@Commit`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/annotation/Commit.html) for don't rollback database. [Spring Testing Annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-spring)

```
//run before test
@Commit
@Transactional
@BeforeTransaction
@Sql({"/start.sql"})//DONT WORK...
public void beforeTransaction()
{
  System.out.println("BEFORE START TRANSACTION");
}


@Test
@Commit
@Transactional
@Sql({"/delete.sql"})
public void sqlTest() {
    System.out.println("TEST RUN");
}
```

start.sql

```
SET search_path users;
-- here create default values
DELETE FROM users;
INSERT INTO users (id,name) (1,'Joe');
INSERT INTO users (id,name) (2,'Jack');
INSERT INTO users (id,name) (3,'Ellie');
```

delete.sql

```
SET search_path users;
--HERE DELETE ONE ROW
DELETE FROM users WHERE name = 'Joe';
```

After run tests, my database has to be in this situation.

```
SET search_path = users;
SELECT * FORM users;
 --------------
|   2  | Jack  |
 ------ -------
|   3  | Ellie |
 ------ -------
```

but that's empty (start.sql) doesn't work

Comment: Well, you're write what you need achieve, but what happens just right now? Some kind of exception, unexpected behavior? How did you understand what `@Sql` doesn't work?

Comment: if start.sql work and insert 3 rows in the database after the test we have 2 column but is empty.

Comment: Ok, i looked to documentation and found this: `Specifically, the @Sql annotation can be declared on a test class or test method`. I think that's mean what `@Sql` can be used only with `@Test` annotated methods. If you really need populate db with this manner i think you may doing this manually, try to use `ResourceDatabasePopulator`.

Answer (score 1):

`@Commit`, `@Transactional`, and `@Sql` are simply not supported on `@BeforeTransaction` and `@AfterTransaction` methods (or any other test lifecycle methods such as `@Before`, `@After`, etc.).

`@Commit`, `@Transactional`, and `@Sql` are only supported at the class level and at the `@Test` method level.

If you want to execute two SQL scripts for a given test method, you have to declare them together on the same test method:

```
@Sql({"/start.sql", "/delete.sql"})
```

... or:

```
@Sql("/start.sql")
@Sql("/delete.sql")
```

If you want the same scripts to be executed for every test method in the same test class, you would then annotate your test class as in the above examples

Note, however, that the presence of `@Sql` on a test method overrides any `@Sql` declarations a the class level.

If you are interested in the possibility to have class-level *and* method-level `@Sql` declarations, see [this Spring issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18929).